# RestSharp api hook never gets called

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I am using restsharp to call the zoom api but the api hook never gets executed. Here is what The tokenString(JWT) is correct when logging it out. No logs appear on zoom.
I have tested through postman with the same paramaters and it works fine. Nothing comes back in my restresponse, it is like it isn't even being called. I am calling this from within an asmx web method
Here is what I have:

```
        var client = new RestClient("https://api.zoom.us");
        var request = new RestRequest("/v2/users/myemail@mycompany.com/meetings", Method.POST)
        {
            RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
        };
        request.AddJsonBody(new { topic = "Meeting with test", duration = "10", start_time = "2021-08-20T05:00:00", type = "2" });
        request.AddHeader("authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", tokenString));
        request.AddHeader("content-type","application/json");
        IRestResponse restresponse = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: What is the response status code?

Comment: I don't get any response. Doesn't look like it gets called at all

Comment: Please check the values of restresponse or paste the exception details if there is one. Please edit your question and add the details.

Comment: Hi Julian, I don't get any response

Answer (score 0):

The issues was with TLS. Posting the following before my call solved it:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```